# Matlab plot — stem3 color gradient bars

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, gradient

I am trying to plot a 3-dimensional stem plot in Matlab using stem3. I need the plot to be with varying color bars depending on the value of the Z axis. Currenytly I am using the following code:

```
  [X,Y] = meshgrid(1:1:4096,1:128);
  B1 = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)permute(x{:},[2 1]),dnl,'UniformOutput',false));

  stem3(X,Y,rot90(B1),'Marker','none');
  xlabel('Code /w offset');
  ylabel('Column');
  zlabel('DNL');
  title('Surface plot of DNL for 128 columns');
```

Unfortunately, this produces a fixed color plot, which is not very meaningful for my situation. Here:

[image: 3-dimentional stem3 plot without color gradient]

Could anyone give a hint on how I can achieve plotting the stem bars with a color gradient depending on the value of the Z axis?

Comment: User `surf` for this

Comment: I've tried surf, but the data I am trying to represent is better displayed with individual bars, rather than connected data points as a surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, I would use `imagesc` instead (Also you forgot to write in your example what `dnl` contains):

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:1:4096,1:128);
B1 = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)permute(x{:},[2 1]),dnl,'UniformOutput',false));
imagesc(X,Y,rot90(B1));
xlabel('Code /w offset');
ylabel('Column');
title('Surface plot of DNL for 128 columns');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: dnl is a 1x128 cell containing 1x4096 double arrays. Should I assume that imagesc would yield a 2D image plot with varying data point color depending on its magnitude?

Comment: @DeyanLevski assume? you can try, no need to assume. Also this code only changes `stem3` by `imagesc`

Comment: @kronos Thanks for the advice! imagesc yields beautifully displayed data. To others who might benefit from these ideas: imagesc needs X-Y vectors, instead of matrixes in the stem3 case.

Comment: @DeyanLevski, no problem. Glad it worked, additionally you can use colorbar and get the color coding. Cheers